# Run on UI thread updates only the last desired result (Android)

Tags: java, multithreading, android

I am trying to do some task of updating the UI on the basis of elapsed time, following is my code:

My OnCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    estimatedTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000;
    tx.postInvalidate();
    System.out.println(""+estimatedTime);
      MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while (estimatedTime <= 100){
                System.out.println(""+estimatedTime);

                if(estimatedTime == 10){
                    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    tx.setText("Shri Ram Raksha Stotram"); 
                    System.out.println("Yay");
                }
                if(estimatedTime == 20){
                    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    tx.setText("Inatializing"); 
                    System.out.println("Yay");
                }
                if(estimatedTime == 30){
                    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    tx.setText("Preparing to install"); 
                    System.out.println("Yay");
                }
                if(estimatedTime == 40){
                    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    tx.setText("Installing"); 
                    System.out.println("Yay");
                }
                if(estimatedTime == 50){


                    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    tx.setText("Installed"); 
                    System.out.println("Yay");
                }
                if(estimatedTime == 60){
                    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    tx.setText("Unzipping packages..."); 
                    System.out.println("Yay");
                }


                estimatedTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

All of the above code is on the OnCreate method, however even after implementing a RunonUI thread I am not able to update the textview, the only result I get on the textview is the last if condition "Unzipping Packages". Where am I going wrong?

Comment: everytime you initialize and setText. if you need to append text to textview use append instead of settext

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call runOnUiThread() inside onCreate(), since onCreate() itself runs on UI thread.

Comment: But then if I do not use it, the TextView wont update? How do I separate code from onCreate? I mean how do I branch it, sorry for sounding confusing but I cant explain it better!

Answer (score 0):

It's unzipping/installing too fast, it's the problem.

So if you want to see all log just **append** text with **+= operator** to your textview if you want to see operations step by step then use `Thread.Sleep(500);` in your every if statements

Comment: Can you please guide me more on the += operator and how to use it?

Comment: Actually it means: String tmpString="";  tmpString+="a"; MEANS tmpString=tmpString+a;

It's same as int or double or whatever :)